# A Conceptual doubt on Binomial Theorem Fractional index.

Tags: binomial-theorem

I am coming across this problem on Binomial Theorem Fractional index.

In the book the author states that :–

> By actual evolution, we have
>
> $(1+x)^{1/2}=\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{8}x^2+\frac{1}{16}x^3-...............;$
>
> and by actual division,
>
> $(1-x)^{-2}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+................;$

*Here, I don't really get the idea of how one can get an infinite series out of these kinds of terms (terms having fractional index).*

I know what "actual division" means and that it gives this infinite series but *I have never heard of "actual evolution"*.

So, I have 2 main questions to ask.

**Is there a more convincing way to look at this equation?**

And,

**What is "actual evolution" and how do you use it?**

Comment: I have never heard the term "actual evolution". Your book may/should explain it before using it. Power series can be found using formal manipulation (your "actual division") and as the Taylor expansions of functions. Perhaps that is "actual evolution".

Comment: I am reading Higher Algebra by Hall and Knight. They didn't explain anything about "actual evolution" before using it.

Comment: @EthanBolker Does learning Power, Taylor, Exponential and Macleurian series require any Calculus knowledge? Because I want to learn them but I have no idea where to get started.

Comment: Yes, those are calculus topics. I've no idea how Hall & Knight introduce them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first few terms in the binomial theorem are
\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+x)^n =1+ nx +\frac{n(n-1)}{2} x^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}x^3+\cdots.
\end{eqnarray*}
Substitute $n=1/2$ will rapidly give you the equation stated in your question. I guess "evolution" should be "evaluation" & this is a typo?

Comment: It seems that you are correct as no explanation is given about the "actual evolution" in the book.

Comment: Is there no other way to prove or find the infinite extension of (1+x)^n. Perhaps a more general way which uses maybe power series etc. (I have no knowledge about power series, but I have heard that it a very fundamental series).

Comment: You could differentiate & use the Taylor series ... but it would give you the same thing.